# Derivative of sigmoid assuming input is a matrix

Tags: matrix-calculus

I do know how to calculate the derivative of sigmoid function assuming the input is a scalar. How to properly derive the derivative of sigmoid function assuming the input is a matrix - i.e. using matrix calculus? The fraction (a sort of division) looks weird in there.

Here are my vague ideas (inspired on how it is coded):
$$
\sigma(\mathbf{X}) = \frac{1}{1 + \exp(-\mathbf{X})}
$$
\begin{split}
\mathrm{d} \sigma(\mathbf{X}) & = \frac{-1 \left[ \exp(-\mathbf{X}) \odot \mathrm{d} (-\mathbf{X}) \right]}{\left( 1 + \exp(-\mathbf{X}) \right)^2} =\\
& = \frac{-1 \left[ \exp(-\mathbf{X}) \odot (-\mathbf{1}) \odot \mathrm{d} \mathbf{X} \right]}{\left( 1 + \exp(-\mathbf{X}) \right)^2} = \\
& = \frac{ \mathbf{1} \odot \exp(-\mathbf{X}) \odot  \mathrm{d} \mathbf{X} }{\left( 1 + \exp(-\mathbf{X}) \right)^2} = \\
& = \frac{\mathbf{1}}{1 + \exp(-\mathbf{X})} \odot \frac{\exp(-\mathbf{X}) + \mathbf{1}  - \mathbf{1} }{1 + \exp(-\mathbf{X})} \odot \mathrm{d} \mathbf{X} =\\
& = \sigma(\mathbf{X}) \odot (\mathbf{1} - \sigma(\mathbf{X})) \odot \mathrm{d} \mathbf{X}
\end{split}

The result matches how I would code it yet the derivation just does not seem right.

Comment: $\sigma(X)$ will transform each element $X_{i,j}$ to $\sigma(X_{i,j})$. So taking the derivative with respect to $X$ means taking the derivative of each $\sigma(X_{i,j})$ with respect to $X_{i,j}$ where $X_{i,j}$ is a scalar. Your derivation seems to me to be correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think things can be made a little simpler than your (correct) derivation.
Let $\sigma:\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ apply the sigmoid function to each element. 
Then, just follow the chain rule for matrix calculus:
$$
\frac{d}{dX}\sigma(X) 
= \frac{\partial \sigma}{\partial X}\frac{\partial X}{\partial X} 
= \frac{\partial \sigma}{\partial X}
= \sigma(X)\odot[\textbf{1} - \sigma(X)]
$$
where $\odot$ is the Hadamard product and $[\textbf{1}]_{ij}=1\;\forall\;i,j$.
We can make the final step with the observation that:
$$
\left[\frac{\partial\sigma}{\partial X}\right]_{ij}
=
\frac{\partial}{x_{ij}}\sigma(x_{ij})
=
\sigma(x_{ij})[1 - \sigma(x_{ij})]
$$
which follows from the scalar definition of the sigmoid.